# How can I call a powershell script from a batch file and return multiple values to the batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file and I want to call a powershell script that returns several values to the batch file.

I've tried to do it by setting environment variables, but that does not work.

This is the batch file:

```
::C:\temp\TestPScall.bat
@echo off
powershell -executionpolicy Bypass -file "c:\temp\PStest.ps1"
@echo [%psreturncode%]
@echo [%uservar%]
@echo [%processvar%]
```

This is the powershell script:

```
# c:\temp\PStest.ps1
$env:psreturncode = "9990"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("UserVar", "Test value.", "User")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ProcessVar", "Test value.", "Process")
```

WHen I run it, the environment variables are not populated.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Enviromental Varibles are loaded on the startup of CMD and not reloaded. You have to retart CMD

Comment: Rather than trying to call PowerShell from a batch file and retrieving output values, I would recommend just writing the entire script in PowerShell in the first place. (It would help to know specifically what problem you are really trying to solve, though.)

Comment: I have a lot of batch files and am in a conversion process to powershell.  I'm converting the 'utility' batch files which are called by other batch files into powershell, and will later convert the larger batch files to ps, so still need to call ps from .bat

Answer (score 0):

As stated in above comment environment variables are changed per session. So you've to start a new `cmd` instance after the PS script ran. Alternatively you can also try to call `refreshenv` from cmd, but I'm not sure if that will work, since docu states that it'll reload values from the registry.

If you want to change an environment variable in a persistent way you've to change them via  system settings.

From [about environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-6#changing-environment-variables) :

> To make a persistent change to an environment variable, use System in Control Panel (Advanced tab or the Advanced System Settings item) to store the change in the registry.
>
> When you change environment variables in PowerShell, the change affects only the current session. This behavior resembles the behavior of the Set command in Windows-based environments and the Setenv command in UNIX-based environments.

Comment: What is missing?

Comment: The enviromenal varible is being set into the user scope and you can access it from CMD. The problem is CMD loads the environmental variables at the start of CMD. When CMD is restarted the enviromental varibles created in powershell then appear. I can even close powershell and close CMD. Reopen CMD and the EV set in powershell sill still appear

Comment: So is there a way to either set an environment variable that the calling batch file will be able to access, OR to return multiple discrete values to the calling batch file (other than with some type of delimited string)?

Answer (score 0):

Lets talk about why this doesnt work.

CMD loads its environmental variables at the start of the application.

So when you update the environmental variables in Powershell then try to call them from the same script it cant find them because they were not loaded into CMD.

If you restart CMD those environmental variables will exist.

There are applications that work around this and set the environmental variables in CMD without restart.

AS Moerwald stated you can use `refreshenv` but thats not a built in command in windows. That comes from Chocolatey. Link Below :

[chocolatey's RefreshEnv.cmd](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/master/src/chocolatey.resources/redirects/RefreshEnv.cmd) is a popular one.

Comment: @LotPings All i am saying is I ran what he ran. I was able to get the Enviromental vars into CMD by just restarting CMD. I closed powershell and closed CMD. i opened CMD again and those EV still were there. Well let me state the process one was not but the user one was.

Answer (score 0):

Have powershell call cmd or bat file?

```
C:\users\js> powershell $env:a = 'there'; cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1150]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\users\js> echo %a%
there
```